# SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I have installed jenkins on my Linux but it is giving following errors when I attempt to start the server as illustrated below.  (Note that I have changed the port also using --httpport.)

I have latest version of java installed on my pc.

Can any one tell me what is causing the following problem?

```
pcadmin@IMSEZ-D0137:~/Desktop$ java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9000
Running from: jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
05-Feb-2013 8:04:10 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
05-Feb-2013 8:04:11 p.m. hudson.WebAppMain contextInitialized
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:253)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:104)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:876)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:87)
   at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:47)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:177)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
   at Main._main(Main.java:273)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.isOpenJDK(JVM.java:72)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.canUseSun14ReflectionProvider(JVM.java:198)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.bestReflectionProvider(JVM.java:175)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:431)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:323)
   at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:78)
   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<clinit>(Jenkins.java:3763)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   ...12 more
05-Feb-2013 8:04:11 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Error during context startup for webapp webapp
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:253)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:104)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:876)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:87)
   at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:47)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:177)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
   at Main._main(Main.java:273)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.isOpenJDK(JVM.java:72)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.canUseSun14ReflectionProvider(JVM.java:198)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.bestReflectionProvider(JVM.java:175)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:431)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:323)
   at hudson.util.XStream2.<init>(XStream2.java:78)
   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<clinit>(Jenkins.java:3763)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   ...12 more
05-Feb-2013 8:04:16 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=9000
05-Feb-2013 8:04:16 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: AJP13 Listener started: port=8009
05-Feb-2013 8:04:16 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Error during servlet context shutdown
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins.model.Jenkins
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:336)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.destroy(WebAppConfiguration.java:1167)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.destroyWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:148)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.destroy(HostConfiguration.java:156)
   at winstone.HostGroup.destroy(HostGroup.java:77)
   at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:337)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:199)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
   at Main._main(Main.java:273)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
05-Feb-2013 8:04:16 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
05-Feb-2013 8:04:16 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener
   at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:229)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:185)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.10)
   at Main._main(Main.java:273)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: winstone.ssl.HttpsListener
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.10)
   at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:213)
   ...5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.util.DerValue not found in java.net.URLClassLoader{urls=[file:/tmp/winstonev2gtdejar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:jenkins.war], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
```

Comment: I have edited the Question to make it clear what the OP is actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar report: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/BqQxg8AByXY/-Rs3rmWKWYYJ

According to the initial response, this is cause by using 'gcj'.  The solution is to use OpenJDK or an Oracle JDK.

Comment: Please vinay patel, mark this answer as the correct solution.