# Jenkins fails with "SEVERE: Error during context startup for webapp webapp" on start

Tags: java, jenkins

I installed Jenkins in Ubuntu 12.04. I changed the port to 8888.

```
root@kandabap-ThinkCentre-M91p:/etc/default# dpkg -l | grep jenkins
ii  jenkins                                1.518                                   Continuous integration system written in Java

root@kandabap-ThinkCentre-M91p:/etc/default# java -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.6.3
```

When I start Jenkins, it stays active for a while and then dies.

Log shows:

```
 18/06/2013 4:08:39 p.m. winstone.Logger logInternal  
    SEVERE: Error during context startup for webapp webapp
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.12)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:253)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:104)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:876)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:129)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:71)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:87)
   at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:47)
   at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:177)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:384)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.12)
   at Main._main(Main.java:288)
   at Main.main(Main.java:98) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.isOpenJDK(JVM.java:128)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.canUseSun14ReflectionProvider(JVM.java:279)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.JVM.bestReflectionProvider(JVM.java:254)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:438)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:381)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:336)
```

How can I get Jenkins up and running in my machine?

Comment: @ suj : Is there a reason below answer is not accepted?

Comment: @ Jayan: Below answer could be a right one. But I am not able to install the open JDK as suggested. Error message is "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.".... I did update and upgrade several time. No clue what is going wrong. When I had the same issue while trying to install Jenkins, it worked after I did system update and upgrade. But no luck at this instance yet. Any comments about this problem ?

Comment: @Try oracle jdk installer.

Comment: @Jayan, Installed oracle jdk. but fails to launch. I suspect something went wrong with my machine... Will chase that out..

Comment: @Jayan, I finally found some luck. I installed 32 bit Java on 64bit machine. Installed 64 bit version. All good now. Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Echoing the answer below, this looks like a duplicate: [SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710095/severe-failed-to-initialize-jenkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as [SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710095/severe-failed-to-initialize-jenkins) I think.

"According to the initial response, this is cause by using 'gcj'. The solution is to use OpenJDK or an Oracle JDK."

Comment: Thanks. I followed that link.
Should I get rid of all the versions of GCJ(in my machine) completely by hand?
and any advice on what version of OpenJDK and Oracle JDK?(if version matters)

Comment: @ suj : Install the correct version, launch java using absolute path.  No need to remove gcj, if you are using it for something else.